# Optimization for password cracker code;

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, passwords

for a class project I decided to make a password generator using all of the printable characters in the asci table (except the minus sign) and then the program will try to crack it.
The password characters are stored in an array and the attempts to crack it are stored in another array. The attempts are just randomized characters and then are compared against the entire password array. If all the characters in both arrays match the program is terminated...if not the loop continues. The problem with my program is that it takes way too long to match the arrays since the attempts are just randomized numbers. Could you help me optimize the code by developing a strategic way to check the password? Even psuedocode helps. Thank You.

The ... is just a loading bar.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a[1000], length, random, b[1000], c[1000], tries = 0; 
bool cracked = false;

cout << "Enter a password length: ";
cin >> length;

srand(time(NULL));
for (int i =0; i<length; i++){
    do {
        random = (rand()%94)+33;
    }while(random==45);
    a[i] = random;
    cout << char(a[i]);
}cout << endl;

do{
    for(int i =0; i<length; i++){
        do{
            random = (rand()%94)+33;
        }while(random==45);
        b[i] = random;
    }
    for(int k=0; k<length; k++){
        if(b[k]==a[k])
            c[k]=0;
        else
            c[k]=1;
        cracked=false;
        if(c[length-1]==0)
            cracked = true;
        else if(c[length-1]==1){
            k=0;
            cracked = false;
            tries++;
            cout << "... ";
        }
    }
}while(cracked==false);

for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    cout << char (b[i]);
cout << "\nNumber of tries: " << tries << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know anything about calculus, Big-Oh notation, benchmarking, or any other type of optimization? Also, wouldn't it take a hell of a lot less time if you were randomizing the password, but then being methodical about cracking it (i.e. random guesses means you might repeat a random number of guesses a random number of times)? I mean...the entropy (if you know what that is) is too great when you just randomly guess.

Answer (score 1):

Your code just make random guesses, and you do not prevent it making duplicate guess.

Have you tried sequential brute force? It take half one minute on length of 5, slightly better than your approach.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a[1000];
int length;
int random;
int b[1000] = { 33 };
unsigned long long tries = 0;
bool cracked = false;

cout << "Enter a password length: ";
cin >> length;

srand(time(NULL));
for (int i =0; i<length; i++){
    do {
        random = (rand()%94)+33;
    }while(random==45);
    a[i] = random;
    cout << char(a[i]);
}cout << endl;

do{
    b[0]++;
    for(int i =0; i<length; i++){
        if (b[i] >= 94 + 33){
            b[i] -= 94;
            b[i+1]++;
        }else break;
    }
    cracked=true;
    for(int k=0; k<length; k++)
        if(b[k]!=a[k]){
            cracked=false;
            break;
        }
    if( (tries & 0x7ffffff) == 0 )
        cout << "\r       \r   ";
    else if( (tries & 0x1ffffff) == 0 )
        cout << ".";
    tries++;
}while(cracked==false);

cout << "\r       \n";
for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    cout << char (b[i]);
cout << "\nNumber of tries: " << tries << endl;

return 0;
}
```

p.s. On windows platform, printing texts to console is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know of any patterns in the password which you can use to devise an algorithm (i.e. restrict the search space) you are left with the monte carlo simulation approach. That is, generate all the possible outputs.  The difference compared to what you are already doing is that you never repeat values, you have a systematic approach to solving the problem and you will cover all the search space (your version will have this problem after running for a while) plus you don't need any extra memory to store the already generated values.

Since this is brute force, the only hope you have of optimizing anything is to parallelize the code - have it run on multiple threads, make use of your architecture's pipeline and so on.